# AAPT: error: unexpected element <property> found in <manifest><application>

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-manifest

I am getting the error

```
AAPT: error: unexpected element <property> found in <manifest><application>
```

in the file

```
(MyUser)\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f8eb949f3b3f333139f5fde4ce67e9c7\jetified-play-services-ads-lite-22.4.0\AndroidManifest.xml:82:9-84:62
```

from the block

```
<property
    android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
    android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config" />
```

when trying to rebuild my android studio project. Thanks for the help.

I haven´t tried much since the file is protected.

Comment: Did you end up solving the problem?

Comment: bumping  up!  We also encountered the same issue. Did any of you find resolution?

Answer (score 3):

I ran onto this problem in my project on updating Google Admob from 22.1 to 22.6. Switching back to 22.1 solved the problem. Maybe there is version between 22.1 and 22.6, that also work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

1. min Unity Gradle 6.7.1
2. Assets/Plugins/Android/baseProjectTemplate.gradle com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1